# Как в Roslyn выполнить код с точки входа

Tags: c#, roslyn

Нужно сделать, чтобы пользователь мог выполнять C#-код на моем сервере (что-то вроде [dotnetfiddle.net](http://dotnetfiddle.net)). Приложение Asp.net Core.

Есть такой метод, который вполне нормально работает:

```
public static async Task<ScriptState<object>> ExecuteScriptAsync(string code, IEnumerable<Assembly> references,
    IEnumerable<string> usings)
{
    var options = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(references).WithImports(usings);

    return await CSharpScript.RunAsync(code, options);
}
```

Проблема метода `ExecuteScript` в том, что такой код он уже не будет выполнять:

```
class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        throw new System.Exception();   
    }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы код выполнялся как в консольном приложении, т.е. метод `Main` был точкой входа?

---

**Update**

Нашел такой код. Срабатывает, но если в скрипт дописать `Console.WriteLine("hi")`, то он ломается с ошибкой "Имя `Console` не существует в текущем контексте".

```
var script = @"using System;
                public static class Program
                {
                    public static int Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        var x = 7 * 8;
                        return x;
                    }
                }";

var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var refs = new List<PortableExecutableReference>
{
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "mscorlib.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Core.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll")),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
};

// Parse the script to a SyntaxTree
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(script);
var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication);
// Compile the SyntaxTree to a CSharpCompilation
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Script",
    new[] { syntaxTree },
    refs,
    new CSharpCompilationOptions(
        OutputKind.ConsoleApplication,
        optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release,
        assemblyIdentityComparer: DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default));

//CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = new CodeDomProvider();
using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdbStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Emit assembly to streams.
    var result = compilation.Emit(outputStream, pdbStream);
    if (!result.Success)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Load the emitted assembly.
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(outputStream.ToArray(), pdbStream.ToArray());

    // Invoke the entry point.
    var x = assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assembly.Load, тем более из массива байт - очень плохая идея, ведь она не дает возможности впоследствии выгрузить сборку из памяти, т.е. при работе в серверном приложении память рано или поздно исчерпается и сервер придется перезапускать. Кроме того, как ограничить права для запускаемого кода, чтобы он не разрушил вам систему? Если вы ориентируетесь под .NET Core, то домены приложений недоступны. Правильнее скомпилировать код в файл и запускать его в новом процессе под пользователем с ограниченными правами и перехватывать его вывод:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace RoslynTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void RunScript()
        {
            var script = @"using System;
                public static class Program
                {
                    public static int Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        var x = 7 * 8;
                        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
                        return x;
                    }
                }";

            var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            var refs = new List<PortableExecutableReference>
            {
                 MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                 MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "mscorlib.dll")),
                 MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Core.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
            };


            // Parse the script to a SyntaxTree
            var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(script);
            var options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication);
            // Compile the SyntaxTree to a CSharpCompilation
            var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Script",
                new[] { syntaxTree },
                refs,
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(
                    OutputKind.ConsoleApplication,
                    optimizationLevel: OptimizationLevel.Release,                    
                    assemblyIdentityComparer: DesktopAssemblyIdentityComparer.Default)
                    );

            var result = compilation.Emit("script.exe");
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot compile script");
            }            

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = "script.exe";
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
            psi.UserName = "Vasya";
            psi.Password = "123";

            var process = new Process();
            using (process)
            {
                process.StartInfo = psi;                
                process.Start();

                while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string res = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();                    
                    Console.WriteLine(res);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код заточен под .NET Framework / Windows, но думаю, не составит труда переделать под .NET Core, так как все используемые библиотеки есть в .NET Standard. Запуск процессов от имени другого пользователя должен работать в .NET Core на всех ОС, начиная с .NET Core 2.1.

---

**Примечание.** В .NET Core 3.0 появилась [возможность выгрузки сборок из памяти](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#assembly-unloadability), но это все еще не решает проблему обеспечения безопасности.