# Как создавать модули проверки кода, такие как Hackerrank, на C#

Tags: c#, .net

Я заинтересован в создании платформы для проверки кода C# (Как у hackerrank.com). Искал в поисковиках, но конкретного примера и алгоритма не нашел. Может кто сталкивался с подобным проектом, поделитесь опытом.

Comment: В плане проверки, что код выдаёт определённый ответ на определённых данных? `unittest`, например, хотя как туда проверку времени выполнения и ресурсов прикрутить не знаю. Но правильность работы кода через него можно проверить. Ну и `pytest` ещё как вариант.

Comment: Вообще Roslyn может помочь откомпилировать код из строки. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918122/373567 а дальше выполняете код как обычно, сверяете результат.

Comment: я бы предположил, что код дополняется обвязкой для запуска (чтобы считывать данные с консоли и писать в консоль результат) и после компилится и запускается через командную строку. И время работы и память уже считается для процесса. Таким образом и тесты и оценку можно отвязать от языка программирования сразу - она пишется 1 раз и навсегда, а добавление нового языка означает только добавление обвязки для него, чтобы скомпилировать и считать/писать в консоль.

Comment: и сами тесты скорее всего на каких то воспроизводимых виртуалках работают или докере, чтобы код не мог выйти за периметр виртуалки. Чтобы тесты себе на почту нельзя было отправить и вывод виртуалки из строя не ломал систему

Comment: ну и прикрутить к этому какой то брокер сообщений (чтобы была очередь проверки) + всякие метрики для сниятия и хранния результатов запуска кода + ранжирование юзеров (чтобы не просто решали, а за морковку) + веб морда, куда решения слать = и вот уже почти готовая система