# Чем заменить CompileAssemblyFromFile, CompileAssemblyFromDom и CompileAssemblyFromSource?

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, entity-framework, компиляция

С помощью CodeDom во время выполнения приложения генерирую простой класс с парой свойств и записываю в .cs файл, но использовать этот класс не могу, так как [компиляция не поддерживается платформой начиная с.NET Core и выше](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

**Подробнее:**
Требуется создать приложение - обработчик логов большого размера (5-10 Гб). Логи в json-формате, каждая json записана в текстовый документ построчно. Набор ключей в каждом лог-файле может быть разный, поэтому требуется динамически создавать модель данных и использовать её для создания временной БД, наполнения и чтения данных.
С помощью CodeDom получается успешно генерировать файл .cs формата через парсинг ключей json-файлов, который будет содержать и нужно пространство имён, и нужное название класса, и все необходимые поля. Но использовать эту модель для чего-либо не получается из-за ограничений платформы.

Была мысль вызывать командную строку или терминал в зависимости от операционной системы, на которой запущено приложение, и через неё запускать команду dotnet и компилировать библиотеку, а потом на лету подключать к работающему приложению и вытягивать нужную модель через reflection, но, мне кажется, должен способ проще и лаконичнее.
К сожалению, других способов не вижу.
Прошу помощи по следующим вопросам:

1. Можно ли создать экземпляр класса, созданного через CodeDom, в .NET Core или .NET 5+ (требуется кроссплатформенность)?
2. Можно ли использовать автоматически сгенерированный класс, записанный в .cs файл, в запущенном приложении? Использовать = создать экземпляр и обращаться к свойствам.
3. Можно ли скомпилировать библиотеку в кроссплатформенной среде через запущенное приложение? Какие есть варианты?
4. Какие ещё есть варианты динамического построения модели в работающем приложении для полноценного использования с EntityFramework?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что теперь такие штуки делаются через Roslyn

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn ([почитать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/net-core-cross-platform-code-generation-with-roslyn-and-net-core)), ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918122/373567))